# what is the meaning of this php code in facebook style chat script freichat?

Tags: php

This question is about the facebook style chatting script [freichat](http://evnix.com/drupal2/) .
The following line is found in arg.php file. Please notice that arg.php is also used in the argument of str_replace(,,.,,) function.

```
    $parameters=
unserialize(file_get_contents(str_replace('arg.php','config.dat',__FILE__)));
```

config.dat file content looks like :

```
a:20:{s:9:"show_name";s:5:"guest";s:11:"displayname";s:4:"name";s:11:
"show_module";s:7:"visible";s:9:"chatspeed";s:4:"5000";s:5:"fxval";s:4:
"true";s:9:"draggable";s:6:"enable";s:8:"conflict";s:4:"true";s:12
```

What does the quoted line actually do? any step by step explanation?

Comment: Step by step: 1) str_replace('arg.php','config.dat',__FILE__) - get full path of config.dat (As it is in the same folder - we can just get full path of current file (__FILE__ predefined constant) and replace curren't script's name with another script's name). 2) file_get_contents() - read that file. 3) unserialize(): convert serialized array (config.dat contents) to PHP array.

Comment: i see, but replacing a file's name sees to be so idiosyncratic to me

Comment: Well, honestly I will never use something like this in production, but I have seen weirder stuff and this seems to work (at least if no one names one of the parent directories "arg.php").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.dat is just a serialized array..

```
unserialize(file_get_contents(str_replace('arg.php','config.dat',__FILE__)));
```

Comment: what is the explanation of str_replace('arg.php','config.dat', __FILE__) ?

Comment: arg.php is the file your searching through, config.bat is what your replacing {keys} with, __FILE__ are they elements your re-placing withn the class/filethe replacement definitions

Comment: opposed to what u say, XzKto said , 'replace curren't script's name with another script's name'. do u agree?

Comment: `__FILE__` is a PHP magic constant that contains the full path of the current file (in this case `arg.php`). And the `str_replace` is used to replace the file name with `config.dat`, so `file_get_contents` gets a complete path to `config.dat`. That way you can be sure that it always reads the `config.dat` that's in the same folder as `arg.php` and not any other `config.dat` that might be in the standard include path for PHP.